# What would I get using Java File.delete() with UNC path if the server response time out

Tags: java, java-io, samba, smb, java.nio.file

I have a rather theoritical question for you.

What would happen if one calls java.io.File#delete() using a UNC path i.e. new File("\192.168.10.10\MyShare\myFile.txt").delete() and the underlying SMB_COM_DELETE request reaches the SMB server but the SMB_COM_DELETE_RESPONSE does not reach the caller back for some reason (network failure, firewall or whatever)? I would expect the java call to time out after few seconds but... do you know how many? Do you know if one would get an exception of some kind? Is this configurable? What if I use Files.delete(), would that make any difference?

I couldn't find anything in the java.io.File javadoc for UNC notation other than that it's supported.

I would be very glad if anyone could answer this

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is [20-60 seconds, depending on your software, and version of Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2013/03/27/smb-2-x-and-smb-3-0-timeouts-in-windows.aspx).

I don't think java or the JVM is in charge of doing what you're asking, but rather in the implementation of the JVM, the deletion of this file would be delegated to an OS level library which would do all of the SMB stuff.  So in this case, your question about timeout isn't about the java library in question, but probably about whatever library implements the SMB protocol.

And the answer to that question is "it depends on which SMB library we're talking about".  The link above provides some general timeout parameters for various combinations of Windows, but they look to me to be all over the map.  So I think a safe range based on that data is 20 - 60 seconds.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense - the timeout is depending on the OS SMB implementation. But the tricky part is - java.io.File#delete() delegates the SMB stuff to the OS. If a timeout occurs the SMB can't be sure if the file was actually deleted or not. What would the method return then? I'd expect it to return "false" but since the file may indeed be deleted this would be misleading, don't you think?

Comment: This question isn't answerable without knowing the details of both the JVM and SMB library implementations.  java.io.File has three options - it can return, throw IOException, or security exception.  Which will it do?  It depends on how the underlying library responds.  What would *that library* do?  It depends on its implementation.  You would need to narrow down which implementation you're using, then go diving into implementation docs (or ask a developer of that SMB lib) to get an actual concrete answer.  Without extra details, the best anyone can do I think is "it depends".

Comment: So to periphrase that, how java is going to handle such situations is an implementation specific detail of the OS. Thank you for helping me realise that.